# Why response is null without passing breakpoints and not null after passing breakpoints?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api, async-await, initialization

Faced with a problem where data is returned as null on `request`. However when I debug it with breakpoints it returns correct values.

The code I'm running:

```
public async Task<PagedList<Response>> Handle(ListQuery request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    (int offset, int limit) = request.Paging;
    var filterParams = new FilterParams(request.Id, offset, limit, request.Sort);

    PagedList<MyType> collection = await _repository.GetList(filterParams, cancellationToken);
    PagedList<Response> result = devices.MapItems(_mapper.Map<IEnumerable<Response>>);

    foreach (Response result in result.Items)
    {
        InitializeResponse(result);
    }

    return result;

    async void InitializeResponse(Response result)
    {
        MyType instance = collection.Items.First(c => c.Id == Result.Id);
        IList<MyInnerType> instanceInnerTypeList = await _repository.GetInnerItems(instance.Id, cancellationToken);
        MyInnerType innerType = instanceInnerTypeList.Single(m => m.Name == "Name");

        result.Version = innerType.Version;
        result.Date = innerType.Date;


        result.InnerTypes = _mapper.Map<IList<MyInnerType>>(instanceInnerTypeList);
    }
}
```

The response without putting breakpoints:

```json
[
  {,
    "id": "GUID",,
    "date": null,
    "version": null,
    "innerTypes": null
  }
]
```

The response when I put breakpoints:

```json
[
  {
    "id": "guid",
    "date": "2023-04-11",
    "version": "string",
    "innerTypes": [
      {
        "id": "guid",
        ... (other properties)
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Could you please point out why it's happening and how I can fix it?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Okay I found the reason. Will provide description and explanation about it.
Spoiler `async void`.

Comment: @Charlieface yeah. I will mark this question as duplicate.